# JQuery Autocomplete for various inputs text with same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i have a problem with JQuery Autocomplete.

I have this code:

```
$(function() {
   var aspecto = [
      "homogéneo",
      "heterogéneo",
    ];
    $("#aspecto").autocomplete({
      source: aspecto
    });
});
```

it works perfect, but i want to use the same structure for others inputs only editing the function name and values of 'var', when i put the 2nd block i get nothing for all the input fields.

What's wrong with that?

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may need to make some assumptions in order to help.  First I assume the $("$aspecto") is a typo.  I think you want either by id *$("#aspecto")* or by class *$(".aspecto")*

So if your html is:

```
<div>
  <label for="aspecto">aspecto: </label>
  <input id="aspecto" />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="not-aspecto">not aspecto: </label>
  <input id="not-aspecto" />
</div>
```

then your javascript should be:

```
$(function() {
   var aspecto = [
      "homogéneo",
      "heterogéneo",
    ];
    $("#aspecto").autocomplete({
      source: aspecto
    });

   var notAspecto = [
      "other thing",
      "or not other thing",
    ];
    $("#not-aspecto").autocomplete({
      source: notAspecto
    });
});
```

Here is a functioning example for you to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/np0m99w8/

Comment: Yes. the $("$aspecto") is a typo. I'm using it by ID, and sorry for all the  assumptions you made, i'm a newbie with ajax, usually i do that with a datalist, but is a lot of code in larger forms.